# How can I move a QGraphicsPixmapItem that reachs the right (end) of graphicView to the left (begining) side(like what is happening in the snake game)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a QGraphicsView widget which displays a pixmap item. The user can move the item. When the item reachs the right (or the left) end of the graphicView, I would like  the item enters from the other side (with the same X and Y coordination (like what happens in the snake game)

Comment: You'll need to call setPos() on your pixmap item with the coordinates you want to move it to.

Comment: sorry, but I do not mean moving an pixmapItem!

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

When setting the position of the pixmap, check if it is less than *the width of the [scene rectangle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop)* - *the width of the pixmap* and if `not`, set the position to `zero`.

**Note:** Do a similar check if you move in the oposite direction, i.e. set the position of the pixmap to *the width of the scene rectangle* - *the width of the pixmap*, if it is not greater than the *width of the pixmap*.

## Example

Here is a minimal example I have prepared for you in order to demonstrate how the proposed solution could be implemented:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QPixmap pixmap(64, 64);
    auto *view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    auto *item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap);
    auto *animation = new QVariantAnimation(this);

    view->setScene(new QGraphicsScene(this));
    view->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
    view->setSceneRect(0, 0, 300, 200);
    view->scene()->addItem(item);

    setCentralWidget(view);
    resize(302, 202);

    connect(animation, &QVariantAnimation::valueChanged, [view, item](){
        int x = item->x();

        if (x < (view->sceneRect().width() - item->pixmap().width()))
            item->setX(x + 1);
        else
            item->setX(0);
    });

    animation->setStartValue(0);
    animation->setEndValue(1000);
    animation->setDuration(10000);
    animation->start();
}
```

The code of a more comprehensive example of a Snake Game I have prepared is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-SnakeGame).

Comment: @Abalfazl Moridi, did you try this?

Comment: I want to part of the image that goes from the left side to the right side to enter only one part that goes out to the left.